# SQL Iteration cursor using procedure

Tags: teradata, procedure, cursors

need to create a procedure that works on Teradata. It should be able to read rows from a table one by one and look up those values on a SQL query which would be embedded in the cursor. the sample SQL query is:

SEL A1 from TABLE1 WHERE B1 not in (sel C from table2 where D=(sel D from table3 where E=E1)

VALUES OF A1, TABLE1, B1, AND E1 should be picked up from Other reference table REF1. The cursor should read table REF1 row by row and put those values of every row in the (A1, TABLE1, B1, AND E1) SQL query above. Please help me with for loop cursor.

Comment: Try writing the procedure and if you get stuck post what you have and where you are having the problem. This question is too general to be answered in detail.  You could loop through REF1 with a FOR loop cursor, and use a dynamic cursor inside that (build a string, PREPARE, and OPEN / FETCH / CLOSE). But what does the inner loop do with the data that is fetched?

Comment: This doesn't sound like it needs a stored proc, much less a cursor.  Do you really want to process one row at  time?

Comment: yes need to process one row at a time, and fetched data from the inner sql query should be printed.